# Computer randomly freezes, then green screen, then restarts

Tags: windows-8

I recently bought an ibuypower computer, Intel i5, 16gb ram, Nvidia 660 ti video card. I'm not good with computers but I know the motherboard is an asus.

As soon as I bought the computer I went out and got a computer game (Dragon Age Origins). I installed the game no problem and within 5 mins of playing it, it would just reset my PC. Turns out the BIOS had a "surge overvoltage" setting that was causing the problem and when I turned it off it the problem stopped. Or I thought at least..

Now my problem is that the game will freeze as soon as my character in the game either starts running or even standing still; it locks up! I can watch the CPU fan and it stalls out and then my screen turns green and the PC restarts itself.

I had a friend re-seat everything on the mother board and I even bought a new game hoping it was just the game but the new one does it too. I've downloaded the latest patch for the game and the newest Nvidia driver. Both took around 6 hours because of internet is very slow. Has anyone ran into this problem before or have any advice how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you always had slow internet? Or only since new PC? Either way, update your graphics (as you have), your audio and your Chipset drives! Personally, I'd do a Windows update and make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can watch the CPU fan and it stalls out and then my screen turns green and the PC restarts itself." Do you mean you can see the fan and it stops?

Comment: Yeah the pc has a clear panel on the left side and when I try to play the game the fan slows down allot until the pc freezes. The fan doesn't ever stop until it resets it's self but it slows down allot.

Comment: if this happens on a new PC, bring it back to you where you bought it and get a replacement device.

Comment: Yeah I think I may have to do that. I'm going to try to do a windows update first and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like maybe the PSU isn't big enough for the system or is defective.  The more intense the graphics, the more power being drawn by the graphics card, CPU, drives, etc.  If you can visibly see the fan slowing down, it's a hint in that direction.  Or the fan may be defective, causing the CPU to overheat.  Either can cause such problems.

Either way, if you just got it, return it for a replacement as magicandre1981 suggested.